# How to make a dynamic input tree in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make somthing like this for a website

[category name (textbox)]
[add sub category (button to js function which creates sub category)]
[sub category field (textbox)]
[add sub category (button to js function which creates sub sub category)]
[sub-sub category field (textbox)]
[add sub category (button to js function which creates sub sub sub category)]

and so on...

so basically a large 'unlimited tree' where you can add as many categories, sub categories and sub, sub, sub, sub... categories as you want.

Here's what I have so far...

```
<body>
<script>
    var category = Array();
    var iter = 0;

    function addCategory(div){
        category[iter] = ["", 0];
        newElement = document.createElement('div');
        var content = '<input type="text" onchange="category[' + iter + '][0] = this.value">\
                       <div id="new-sub" style="padding-left: 20px">\
                          <button onclick="addSub(\'new-sub\', ' + category[iter][1] + ', ' + iter + ')">Add Sub-category</button>\
                       </div>';
        newElement.innerHTML = content;
        document.getElementById(div).appendChild(newElement);
        iter++;
    }

    function addSub(div, ID, iter){
        //here lies my confusion
    }

</script>
<div id="new-elements">
</div>
<button onclick="addCategory('new-elements')" >Add Element</button>
</body>
```

I the idea is to store the textbox values in an array as the user changes them. Only issue is I cant seem the get the multi-dimension array part right...

I'm an extreme beginner to JS, can anyone help me find a solution?

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @zer00ne like that?

Comment: it's a start, but we prefer you have the code in a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: There are numerous tree scripts around that will manage this for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created single function for this. Check here:
https://jsfiddle.net/amitabhjoshi04/gzvzz790/

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
        div{
        border:1px solid red;
        padding:10px;
        margin:5px;
        }
        </style>
        <script>
            function addCategory(current){
                var current_level_tree = current.getAttribute('data-level-tree');
                var current_level = parseInt(current.getAttribute('data-level'));
                var existing_same_level_cat = document.getElementsByClassName('class_level_'+(current_level+1));
                existing_same_level_cat = existing_same_level_cat.length;
                var where_append_goes = document.getElementById('level_'+current_level_tree);
                var new_div = document.createElement('div');
                var new_div_id = (current_level+1)+'_'+(existing_same_level_cat+1);
                new_div.setAttribute('id','level_'+new_div_id);
                new_div.setAttribute('class','class_level_'+(current_level+1));
                where_append_goes.appendChild(new_div);

                /* ********************************************************* */
                var new_input = document.createElement('input');
                new_input.setAttribute('name','cate_'+new_div_id);
                new_input.placeholder = 'Add Value To Level : '+(current_level+1);

                new_div.appendChild(new_input);

                /* ******************************************* */
                var new_button = document.createElement('button');
                new_button.setAttribute('onclick',"addCategory(this)");
                new_button.setAttribute('data-level-tree',new_div_id);
                new_button.setAttribute('data-level',(current_level+1));
                new_button.innerHTML = 'Add Element To Level : '+(current_level+1);

                new_div.appendChild(new_button);

            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="level_0_0">

        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="addCategory(this)" data-level-tree="0_0" data-level="0" >Add Element</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you need more help.